# styling database fetched images differently whilst displaying them using django templating for tag

Tags: css, database, image, django-templates

displaying database fetched images using Django templates and style some projects images to be different from the others using CSS.

This could be bad design strategy, but here is what I have: Django template that iterates over a database fetched project images and displays them. I want to be able to style some projects images to be different from the others using CSS. what I was thinking was maybe save some form of data in the database to distinguish the project's images to circumvent the situation of adding more projects in the future or changing some project image and style.  I am not sure if this is a good design practice. any recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: If you're not using css classes in your images, maybe you could get away by using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
For example (in your css) select project images containing the word "project" `img[src*="project"] { ...styles }`

Comment: so you suggesting the difference should be embedded in the images names?

Comment: Well that is just a one way to do it, assuming you would always be sure that images are named correctly. But I recommend you to use CSS class names instead :)